# No BoundingBox in LaTeX for a JPEG figure

Tags: graphics

I am creating a pdf file with MiKTeX editor. I am including a figure as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{MonitoringConcept.JPEG}
    \caption{Monitoring concept for energy and comfort}
    \label{MonitoringConcept}
\end{figure}
```

In the header, I have added these packages:

```
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,subfig,graphicx}
```

However, in the compilation time I get an Error. The message is the next one:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in MonitoringConcept.JPEG (no BoundingBox).
```

Do you know what the problem could be? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How are you compiling the document?

Comment: In my PC I'm using pdfLaTeX and it compiles, but the problem is when I upload the source file to the server. However, I don't know the compiler they are using for that

Comment: In fact, the guideline details the source files must be compiled before uploaded with pdflatex, so I assume they are using the same

Comment: This error happens when you use `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. The former is not able to load JPEG files, only EPS.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.